# HTML5, div, hidden, show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a button at the end. I want that when someone presses that button another div (below the previous one) should appear with the content I have put it inside the div.

I am using the following code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a id="button" href="#">REGISTER</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="item">
    <iframe src="some source" embedded=true" width="760" height="550" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading</iframe>
</div>
```

and the jquery with script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            $( "#item" ).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that the second div is appearing on page load itself initially and when I am clicking on the button its disappearing.
What should I do?

Comment: You need to prevent the default submit action of `a` tag

Comment: @karthikr - His href is `#` so it wouldn't make a difference other than stopping the page from jumping back to the top.

Comment: What style is being applied to the second div? You must default it to hidden, or it will be displayed by default. The reason it disappears is you are calling toggle on it when it is displayed, so it hides it.

Comment: I see you edited the question, so `style` attribute (which had a typo) was removed. My previous comment still applies, though: The element should be initially hidden, so it can be *toggle*d to be visible.

Comment: Could use JQuerys addClass/removeClass to add and remove a class that would contains css `display:none/block`?

Answer (score 19):

HTML5 enables you to do it easily using the **details** tag.

```
<details>
    <summary>Click to toggle division</summary>
    <p>Here you can put some content...</p>
    <p>... and anything else you want :)</p>
</details>
```

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3wqyyf7m/

Comment: Thank you and using internally!  Note that this remains unsupported in late 2016 by IE / Edge : http://caniuse.com/#feat=details

Comment: Under development in Edge as of late 2017

Answer (score 6):

If you want an element to be hidden at first load, you can use the `hidden` attribute;

```html
<div id="item" hidden>...</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xztwnp7f/1/

Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden

This is a relatively new attribute so if you need to support old browsers you can put this in your css to make it work;

```css
*[hidden] { display: none; }
```

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-hidden

Comment: @Sebastien Absolutely, if you love to type :)

Comment: Well the choice between the two is merely a question of do you want the element that is hidden to take up space on your page or not. If you want space on the page to still be allocate even if the element is not visible use `hidden` if not use `display`.

Comment: @Sebastien Incorrect. An element with `display: none;` behaves exactly like `hidden` and will not take up any space - you're probably confusing it with `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @Sebastien Using the `hidden` attribute has the same properties as the css `display:none;`. Using `visibility:hidden;` css is when the space remains allocated.

Comment: @Sebastien No, you are wrong. The `hidden` attribute isn't mentioned at all in that question. The `hidden` attribute appears like this: `<div class="somename" hidden>` where as the css property is a keyword for the `visibility` setting.

Comment: Same name = confusing... Me much dumb me should stop posting stackOveflow XP

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="show">Show Content</button>
    <button type="button" id="hide">Hide Content</button>
</div>
<div id="item" hidden>
    Some hidden content
</div>

$( "#show" ).click(function() {
    $('#item').show(); 
});

$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
    $('#item').hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xztwnp7f/41/)

Answer (score 2):

Create html div

```
 function showhide()
{
   var div = document.getElementById(&ldquo;newpost");

if (div.style.display !== "none") {

div.style.display = "none";

}

else {

div.style.display = "block";

}

 }
```

This div will be show and hide on button click

```
    <button id="button" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

change toggle() to show()
the show() attribute shows the div only. It don't hide the div again when you click again on the button.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
$( "p" ).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Copy-paste from http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you've missed a `"` on `embedded=true"`

There's a number of ways you may want to do this with JQuery; I've added `display: none` to the iframe's CSS rather than add a `style` element.

```
#regFrame{
    display: none;
}

<div>
    <a id="button" href="#">REGISTER</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="item">
    <iframe id="regFrame" src="http://placekitten.com/g/760/550" embedded="true" width="760" height="550" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
        Loading
    </iframe>
</div>

$('#button').click(function(){
    //$('#regFrame').show();
    //$('#regFrame').toggle(); //To hide the iframe when the button is clicked again
    //$('#regFrame').show(500); //To fade in the iframe
    $('#regFrame').toggle(500); //To fade the iframe in and out
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0ojehz4/2/)

Comment: You are totally correct; thus I've amended my answer. In terms of hiding the iframes, that's beyond the scope of the question but I do agree and have updated the css with the ID

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like `details` easily from scratch:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.details').forEach(function(div) {
  div.querySelectorAll('span.handle').forEach(function(span) {
    span.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (div.dataset.expanded == 'true')
        div.dataset.expanded = 'false';
      else
        div.dataset.expanded = 'true';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div.details > span.handle:after {
  pointer-events: all;
}

div.details[data-expanded="true"] > span.handle:after {
  content: '▼';
}

div.details[data-expanded="false"] > span.handle:after {
  content: '►';
}

div.details[data-expanded="true"] > div.body {
  display: table;
}

div.details[data-expanded="false"] > div.body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="details" data-expanded="false">
  <span class="handle"></span>
  <span class="summary">Hello World!</span>
  <div class="body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
    erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
```